# add one point to pandas row if string from list matches column name

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a pandas dataframe with 10 columns and 100 rows, where the first column contains a shopping list description. All other columns are filled with NAN values and the column name is a type of fruit or vegetable.

In addition to this, I have 100 lists with random food items in them, like so `List1 = ['apple','banana','pear']`.

The list is limited to a maximum of 9 items, but sometimes a list can be empty too.

I would now like to iterate over my 100 lists and fill in a 1, if a string in the list matches a column header.

```
List2 = ['smoothie']
```

The final dataframe should look like this:

```
Description | apple | banana | pear| grape | smoothie |
List1           1       1        1     0        0
List2           0       0        0     0        1
```

Comment: If you have 100 lists in different variables, maybe you should first fix that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables.

Comment: @MustafaAydın I'm sure you didn't understand the question, but thank you for commenting.

Comment: Yes, probably; sorry. I also don't understand why the expected frame has a 0 at the bottom right corner.

Comment: That indeed is my mistake, in filling out the values :-) thank you for catching it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for same values and same order like in original `df`:

```
List1 = ['apple','banana','pear']
List2 = []

L = [List1, List2]

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df1 = (pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(L),columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index)
         .reindex(df.columns[1:], fill_value=0, axis=1))
print (df1)
   apple  banana  pear  grape  smoothie
0      1       1     1      0         0
1      0       0     0      0         0

df = df[['Description']].join(df1)
print (df)
  Description  apple  banana  pear  grape  smoothie
0       List1      1       1     1      0         0
1       List2      0       0     0      0         0
```